# Fade in/out animation for a series of dots

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewanimation, cabasicanimation

I have an upload `UIButton` and I'm trying to implement an animation where I have a group of individual dots that line up horizontally underneath the button and have the very left dot fade in/out, then have the dot next to it fade in/out, and so on all the way to the right most dot, then start the cycle over again from the left. I can get this working for one dot, but what would be the most efficient way to do this for multiple dots?

```
func dotAnimation(){
    let xCoord = self.recButt.frame.origin.x + 25
    let yCoord = self.recButt.frame.origin.y + 5
    let radius = 3

    let dotPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: Int(xCoord), y: Int(yCoord), width: radius, height: radius))
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = dotPath.cgPath
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 95.00/255, green: 106.00/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.00).cgColor
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)

    let animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity");
    animation.autoreverses = true
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 1
    animation.duration = 2.0
    layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are describing a CAReplicatorLayer. Here is one that does the sort of thing you're after, using bars instead of dots:

[image]

Here's the code for that. Note that there is only *one* red bar layer; the replication into five, and the offset fading animation, is handled by the containing replicator layer:

```
    let lay = CAReplicatorLayer()
    lay.frame = CGRect(0,0,100,20)
    let bar = CALayer()
    bar.frame = CGRect(0,0,10,20)
    bar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    lay.addSublayer(bar)
    lay.instanceCount = 5
    lay.instanceTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(20, 0, 0)
    let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.opacity))
    anim.fromValue = 1.0
    anim.toValue = 0.2
    anim.duration = 1
    anim.repeatCount = .infinity
    bar.add(anim, forKey: nil)
    lay.instanceDelay = anim.duration / Double(lay.instanceCount)
    // and now just add `lay` to the interface
```

Comment: This looks like it will do it. Just read through the apple documentation. So we in this example there are two layers, lay and the sublayer bar, and lay is being replicated 5 times?

Comment: And that is effectively what you would want to do. Of course my dimensions, shapes, colors, timing, etc., are all parameters you can change completely for your own purposes.

Comment: Alright almost got it working. How can i make it so that only one dot appears at a time, so by the time one dot begins fading in, the one on the left has already faded out. I assume that has to do with `instanceDelay`?

Comment: Yes, it should be a question of juggling the delay and the animation duration. But personally I've always had a little trouble with the fine tuning. :) I usually just stop tweaking when it's "good enough".

Comment: @matt can set different delay for each replication, basically what I want is 1 2 3 then 3, 2,1 , Like show 1 then 1 and  2 then 1, 2 and 3 then 1 and 2 then 1. Is it possible using CAReplicatorLayer?

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, make sure you add the layer elsewhere than viewDidLoad (such as viewDidLayoutSubviews)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version of animating three dots in any `UILabel`

```
private var displayLink: CADisplayLink?

private var loadingLabeltext: String = ""
private var loadingLabel: UILabel? = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = UIColor.appRed
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont.init(name: "CirceRounded-Bold", size: 15)
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.6
    return label
}()

override func viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad(animated)
    
    view.addSubview(loadingLabel!)
    loadingLabel!.text = "Loading ..."
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    animateLabelDots(label: loadingLabel!)
}

private func animateLabelDots(label: UILabel) {
    guard var text = label.text else { return }
    text = String(text.dropLast(3))
    loadingLabeltext = text
    displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(showHideDots))
    displayLink?.add(to: .main, forMode: .common)
    displayLink?.preferredFramesPerSecond = 4
}

@objc private func showHideDots() {
    if !loadingLabeltext.contains("...") {
        loadingLabeltext = loadingLabeltext.appending(".")
    } else {
        loadingLabeltext = "Loading "
    }
    
    loadingLabel!.text = loadingLabeltext
}
```

And when you want to stop it just invalidate and deinitizlize display link like this :

```
private func hideLoadingSpinner() {
    displayLink?.invalidate()
    displayLink = nil
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        loadingLabel?.text = "Finished!"
        loadingLabel?.alpha = 0
    })
}
```